# instantiating generic classes in c#

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, class, generics

In the piece of code below, the output is;

> Ernie 
>   Bert 
>   Elmo

Why is the last output is Elmo? Shouldn't it be Ernie? Because i instantiate `dog.Creature` object with `new Cat();`. i thought that the `Name` property of `Cat` class overrides the `Name` property of `Creature` class.

```
class Class1
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var dog = new Dog();
        var cat = new Cat();
        dog.Creature = new Cat();

        Console.WriteLine(cat.Name); //outputs Ernie
        Console.WriteLine(dog.Name); //outputs Bert 
        Console.WriteLine(dog.Creature.Name); //outputs Elmo, why not Ernie?
        Console.Read();
    }
}
public class Animal<T> where T : Creature
{
    public T Creature { get; set; }
    private string _name = "Oscar";
    public string Name { get { return _name; } set { _name = value; } }
}
public class Creature
{
    private string _name = "Elmo";
    public string Name { get { return _name; } set { _name = value; } }
}
public class Cat : Creature
{
    private string _name = "Ernie";
    public string Name { get { return _name; } set { _name = value; } }
}
public class Dog : Animal<Creature>
{
    private string _name = "Bert";
    public string Name { get { return _name; } set { _name = value; } }
}
```

Comment: This is kinda confusing.

Comment: The compiler is producing a warning that is explaining what is going on here. My advice is that you get in the habit of reading the compiler output when you are trying to understand its behavior.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Firstly, this has nothing to do with generics. You'll get exactly the same behaviour if you write:

```
Creature cat = new Cat();
Console.WriteLine(cat.Name);
```

Don't forget that the compile-time type of `Dog.Creature` is `Creature`.

> i thought that the Name property of Cat class overrides the Name property of Creature class.

No, because it's not a virtual property and you haven't used `override`. You should have a compile-time warning *explicitly* saying that you're hiding the member, not overriding it:

```
Test.cs(30,19): warning CS0108: 'Cat.Name' hides inherited member
        'Creature.Name'. Use the new keyword if hiding was intended.
```

If you change `Cat` and `Creature` to be like this, it will work:

```
public class Creature
{
    private string _name = "Elmo";
    public virtual string Name { get { return _name; } set { _name = value; } }
}

public class Cat : Creature
{
    private string _name = "Ernie";
    public override string Name { get { return _name; } set { _name = value; } }
}
```

... but personally I'd try to avoid this anyway. Why not just use the setter in `Creature`? Why would you want there to be two `_name` fields in a `Cat` object? It's not like they're meant to serve different purposes, is it?

It's not clear what you're trying to achieve, but I'd almost certainly give the `Creature` class a constructor taking the name as a parameter. I'd probably make the property read-only if at all possible, too.

Comment: Thank you for your explanations but the actual problem is not overriding or hiding the property. I mean i compiled this code without any errors.. So the code is allowed by the compiler. Assume that i wrote this code intentionally. I just wonder how this code part: Console.WriteLine(dog.Creature.Name); returns me 'Elmo' ? What are the assumptions?

Comment: @mikail: You compiled it without *errors*, but the code you've provided does give *warnings*, and yes, the problem *is* the failure to override. You thought you were overriding the property, but you weren't. `dog.Creature.Name` will call `Creature.Name`, which isn't called polymorphically (because it's non-virtual).

Comment: Ok, that is understandable but how is it possible that cat calls its own class property but dog.Creature calls its base class property even though dog.Creature is instantiated with Cat class? Shouldn't it call the property of Cat class?

Comment: @mikail: No, because the compile-time type of `dog.Creature` is `Creature`. See the start of my answer (which was edited in a while ago) - once you understand how that works, you're most of the way there.

Answer (score 3):

> I thought that the Name property of Cat class overrides the Name property of Creature class

No, it *hides* it.  You have two different properties with the same name.  If you want to *override* it, you need to make the base property `virtual` and use the `override` keyword on the inherited class:

```
public class Creature
{
    private string _name = "Elmo";
    public virtual string Name { get { return _name; } set { _name = value; } }
}
public class Cat : Creature
{
    private string _name = "Ernie";
    public override string Name { get { return _name; } set { _name = value; } }
}
```

As to *why* you are seeing "Elmo" instead of "Ernie" - it's because `Dog` is an `Animal<Creature>`, so the property `Dog.Creature` is of type `Creature`.  Even though you pass in a `Cat`, since the `Name` property is not *overridden*, `Creature.Name` is called.  If you had *overrode* `Name`, then `Cat.Name` would be called instead.

Comment: So you are saying Dog.Creature is Creature and Name property of Cat class hides the Name property of Creature class when i do: **var cat = new Cat()** .. But how come it doesnt hides when i do: **dog.Creature = new Cat()** ? Doesn't the right side of both instances (new Cat(), new Cat()) hide the left sides' (var cat, dog.Creature) properties? Because both left sides are base classes and both right sides are subclasses..

Comment: `dog.Creature` is a `Creature`.  When you call `dog.Creature.Name` it's calling `Creature.Name`.  Since `Name` is not polymorphic (`virtual`) it _can't_ be overridden by base classes.  To call `Cat.Name` you'd have to explicitly cast it: `((Cat)dog.Creature).Name` which will fail at runtime if the value of `Creature` isn't really a `Cat`.

Answer (score 3):

A good practice is to read the warnings the IDE gives you.

```
warning CS0108: 'Program.Cat.Name' hides inherited member 'Program.Creature.Name'. Use the new keyword if hiding was intended.
warning CS0108: 'Program.Dog.Name' hides inherited member 'Program.Animal<Program.Creature>.Name'. Use the new keyword if hiding was intended.
```